# Format of TextBoxFor for string ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have view model iwth field:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? FirstRegistration { get; set; }
```

And input in form:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstRegistration, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new {@class = "input-sm form-control"})
```

The problem is that sometimes (after returning view when model state is not valid):

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(model);
```

Format is completely ignored. What is wrong?

Comment: When returning ??? are you saying the client posts data in the wrong format back to the client?

Comment: Yes, I suppos that problem could be nullable. `ToString` in nullable has no format argument, so it is ignored and uses `ToString` without any args, so culture-specific format is used.

Comment: if the client returns a value during a round trip to the server and the server code simply rejects it after a ModelState.IsValid check (like most examples go) then the server will likely just return what it was given in the same format from viewstate rather than from the model (does that make sense) ... it could be that the stored value in viewstate isn't right for some reason

Comment: What do you mean the _format is completely ignored_? What value are you posting and what value is then displayed in your textbox?

Comment: The value I post is f.e. "1/1/2016" but "1.1.2015" after post - just like my server settings default culture.